# spree: understanding flow of the demo app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

So I created a spree rails app using their [documentation](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html). I am trying to understand the flow of the app with respect to front-end.

I am trying to understand from where all these tags and images are coming.

All I have is `app/views/spree` and nothing else here. So from where are these views coming in my app?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing - please take a look on this [tutorial on Youtube](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/deface_overrides_tutorial.html). It's showing how to set up Spree including view change by using [Deface](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/deface_overrides_tutorial.html).

### Views

You have to have installed and working Spree instance. Follow these steps:

- locate spree_frontend gem <sup>I'm using bundler and rvm</sup>

  $ bundle show spree_frontend

  /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spree_frontend-3.0.8

  - copy views to your project located in gems (it will be two folders kaminari and spree)

  /Users/kuba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spree_frontend-3.0.8/app/views

When you do this, you have the same file views used in fresh installation. Spree looks for views in you app folder, if not find it gets views from `spree_frontend` gem. You can play a bit and see how frontend is made. Go ahead and change something to see how does it work.

This way is not recommended. If you have overridden files, you can lost extra functionality provided by spree extension gems or get broken app when you decide to upgrade spree

Better way, maybe harder on beginning, will be to to use deface files and store them in `overrides` dir. This is example from my current project. In Spree we have no footer. I wanted to add it the bottom of page right before body closing tag `</body>`.

I added file `add_footer.html.erb.deface` in overrides dir:
[image: overrides structure]

and write deface code:

```
<!-- insert_bottom 'body' -->
<footer id="footer">
    <h4>About us</h4>
     nobody expects the spanish inquisition
</footer>
```

and you have nice footer at the bottom of HTML document
[image]

### Images and CSS

It's like in normal Rails app. Just go to assets. If you want to see what files are used by go to assets in spree_frontend gem.

Answer (score 1):

those views are from the "spree front end" gem which is included in spree gem 
you can find the source for the gem in the github's spree source code. Here is the url

https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/master/frontend

the views are located in

https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/master/frontend/app/views/spree

if you install any extra extension they might include their own views.

for example, when I add blogging extension using my repo

https://github.com/krazedkrish/spree-blogging-spree

this plugin has its own views in the app/views folder in its source.

I hope this explains you clearly.